# Created .desktop launcher is not working in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: .desktop

I wanted to create a shortcut to run a command which will move to a directory and run a command. The problem is that when double-click the launcher, it doesn't do anything. I set check "Allow execute as a programm". This is how my .desktop file looks like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=cd ~/todoist-linux-1.17 && make up 
Name=Todoist
Icon=
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a bash script for the command you want to run and the point the `Exec=` entry to the script.

First create a simple script, i.e. a text file, say a file named `myscript` in your Documents folder with the following text

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/todoist-linux-1.17 && make up
```

and make it executable. Then modify your `.desktop` launcher and for the `Exec` entry use the following

```
Exec=/home/YOUR-USERNAME/Documents/myscript
```

(you need to use absolute paths in the `.desktop` file).

Comment: still, it doesn't run, I included a screenshot of how this shortcut looks like, maybe it is being run with the incorrect application?

Comment: @Viktor You haven't mentioned in the question, but now from the screenshot it looks like you have placed the `.desktop` file in your Desktop. On Ubuntu 19.04, Nautilus (file-manager) does not handle desktop icons, they're provided by a GNOME extension. Currently the extension provides only a limited number of features. Place the `.desktop` file in some other folder and try. If it works, put the `.desktop` file in your `~/.local/share/applications/` folder. Then you would be able to search and launch it from the 'Activities' overview or 'Show Applications' screen.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it has a preloader but it doesn't execute the script, if i did everything correctly, i created todoist.sh script inside Document put the `.desktop` file in the same place and put the full path to script  `Exec=/home/viktor/Documents/todoist` as well tried with `todoist.sh`

Comment: Does just running the command in Terminal work? Not sure what's specific about this command, I tried with some generic and basic commands, it works okay.

Comment: yes i runned the command separetly and it worked

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong here, sorry :( Just to make sure, is your system language English?

Comment: I consider the answer of Synchro as the simplest and more straighforward approach here, but unfortunatelly there are other issues with that anwer.

Answer (score 1):

Your desktop file should look something like this:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Todoist
Exec=bash -c 'cd ~/todoist-linux-1.17 && make up' 
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

You can also set `terminal=false` and replace `Exec=bash -c 'cd ~/todoist-linux-1.17 && make up'` with `Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd ~/todoist-linux-1.17 && make up'"` to run this in gnome terminal.

Comment: i noticed that launcher is not working at all no matter what kind of command i put

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I tried the same thing for a python GUI application. @viktor you should follow the way recommended by @pomsky. After that don't double click on the `.desktop` file. rather find it on the `show application` button (The button on which you can click and browse all the application present in your computer). There you will find the icon. Click and open.