# Custom quick launcher issue in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, launcher

I've added a custom launcher to my desktop to run a script, but when I drag it into the lxqt quick launch panel it does nothing (ie I can put debug stmts in the script and they aren't executed). Any ideas what I'm missing? Here's the launcher:

```
Name=Suspend Screensaver
GenericName=sets xscreensaver to 3h timeout
Comment=Meh
Exec=/home/username/bin/sss
Type=Application
Icon=alexandra
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
OnlyShowIn=LXQt;
```

In panel.conf I get this inserted:

```
apps\5\desktop=/home/username/.local/share/applications/Suspend_screensaver.desktop
```

... and that .desktop file is owned by the user with 644 perms.

Many thanks

Comment: Does the launcher work otherwise, i.e. does it show up in your user menu and can you launch it from there? Does the command you specify work when you execute it in a terminal? Just to be sure it is an LXQt issue and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks vanadium.. The launcher works when I double click on it on my desktop, runs the script successfully and updates the config correctly. It's just when I call it from the quick launch bar, it does nothing. If I enable Terminal=true it launches a blank terminal but doesn't execute the script (although I get that from the desktop too if I set Terminal to true). I used some ```echo text >> /home/username/sss.log``` to confirm the script has run so it's very clear that it works only from double clicking the desktop icon and with Terminal=false

Comment: "does it show up in your user menu and can you launch it from there" - it's in the menus but no, it doesn't work from the menu either. Only as a desktop launcher.

Comment: Found another clue here https://askubuntu.com/a/1154486/1691139 - adding bash -c 'mycommand' did the trick, together with creating the quick launcher by dragging in the menu item rather than the one on my desktop... Hope that helps someone else..!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped the exec value in `bash -c 'mycommand'` and that got it working, together with creating the quick launcher by dragging in the menu item rather than the one on my desktop